# Setting RelativeLayout rules not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the `CameraPreview` example API demo. As preview's overlay, I need to set a button to take the photo.

This is what I'm doing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //...
    btnTakePhoto = new Button(this);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);


    Preview mPreview = new Preview(this); //Preview class implementing SurfaceHolder.Callback       

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cameraParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(mPreview, cameraParams);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    btnTakePhoto.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
    addContentView(btnTakePhoto, buttonParams);
    //...
```

What I do is first create a `RelativeLayout` container. Then I add the `Preview class` to the view, this shows the camera preview.

After that I set some `params` for the button and I add it to the view.

Here is the issue. The views are added overlaying the preview, but the "rules" are not set. This is, the button is shown, but at the top-left side of the screen.

Comment: Where did you want to see the button?

Comment: @Hamid Shatu, As the default camera button, and as I set the parameters in my code: ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, CENTER_VERTICAL... so, at the right side of the screen, in the center_vertical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent layout where `setContentView()` and `addContentView()` place the views is a `DecorView` which is-a `FrameLayout`. `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` does not magically turn it into a `RelativeLayout` and only the generic features of `LayoutParams` such as width and height get applied.

To fix it, add the children directly to your `relativeLayout` and not to the decor view with `addContentView()`. For example:

```
relativeLayout.addView(mPreview, cameraParams);
```

Comment: I new that something like that should be the problem, but I don't know how to do that. How should I add the childrens to the relativelayout?

Comment: @masmic_87 Updated with example

Comment: Thanks! Still got one question. I add the preview and the button this way to the relativelayout, but, How do I set the relativelayout as the container? Now I'm doing `setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp)` but you have said that I can'd do this

Comment: Of course add your root layout i.e. the relative layout as the content view. Just add the other views as children to the relative layout.